# Search through directories for specific Excel files and compare data from these files with inputvalues

Tags: python, eclipse, excel, directory, compare

**The task:**
The firm I have gotten a summer-job for has an expanding test-database that consists of an increasing number of subfolders for each project, that includes everything from .jpeg files to the .xlsx's I am interested in. As I am a bit used to Python from earlier, I decided to give it a go at this task. I want to search for exceldocuments that has "test spreadsheet" as a part of its title(for example "test spreadsheet model259"). All the docs I am interested in are built the same way(weight is always "A3" etc), looking somewhat like this:

```
Model:             259 
Lenght:   meters    27
Weight:   kg      2500
Speed:    m/s       25
```

I want the user of the finished program to be able to compare results from different tests with each other using my script. This means that the script must see if there is an x-value that fits both criteria at once:

```
inputlength = x*length of model 259
inputweight = x*weight of model 259
```

The program should loop through all the files in the main folder. If such an X exists for a model, I want the program to return it to a list of fitting models. The x-value will be a variable, different for each model.

As the result I want a list of all files that fits the input, their scale(x-value) and possibly a link to the file.
For example:

```
Model     scale   Link
ModelA    21.1    link_to_fileA
ModelB    0.78    link_to_fileB
```

**The script**
The script I have tried to get to work so far is below, but if you have other suggestions of how to deal with the task I'll happily accept them. Don't be afraid to ask if I have not explained the task well enough. XLRD is already installed, and I use Eclipse as my IDE. I've been trying to get it to work in many ways now, so most of my script is purely for testing.

***Edited:***

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Accepts norwegian letters

import xlrd, os, fnmatch

folder = 'C:\eclipse\TST-folder'



  def excelfiles(pattern):
    file_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_dir):
        for filename in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename.lower(), pattern):
                if filename.endswith(".xls") or filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith(".xlsm"):
                    file_list.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return file_list

file_list = excelfiles('*tst*')     # only accept docs hwom title includes tst

print excelfiles()
```

How come I only get one result when I am printing excelfiles() after returning the values, but when I exchange "return os.path.join(filename)" with "print os.path.join(filename)"  it shows all .xls files? Does this mean that the results from the excelfiles-function is not passed on? **Answered in comments**

```
''' Inputvals '''
inputweight = int(raw_input('legg inn vekt')) #inputbox for weight
inputlength = int(raw_input('legg inn lengd')) #inputbox for lenght
inputspeed = int(raw_input('legg inn hastighet')) #inputbox for speed

    '''Location of each val from the excel spreadsheet'''
    def locate_vals():
    val_dict = {}
    for filename in file_list:
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(start_dir, filename))
        sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

        weightvalue = sheet.cell_value(1, 1)
        lenghtvalue = sheet.cell_value(1, 1)
        speedvalue = sheet.cell_value(1, 1)

        val_dict[filename] = [weightvalue, lenghtvalue, speedvalue]

    return val_dict
val_dict = locate_vals()
print locate_vals()


count = 0
```

Any ideas of how I can read from each of the documents found by the excelfiles-function? "funcdox" does not seem  to work. When I insert a print-test, for example print weightvalue after the weightvalue = sheet.cell(3,3).value function, I get no feedback at all.  Errormessages without the mentioned print-test:**Edited to the script above, which creates a list of the different values + minor changes that removed the errormessages**

***Script works well until this point***

Made some minor changes to the next part. It is supposed to scale an value from the spreadsheet by multiplying it with a constant (*x1*). Then I want the user to be able to define another inputvalue, which in turn defines another constant(*x2*) to make the spreadsheetvalue fit. Eventually, these constants will be compared to find which models will actually fit for the test.

```
    '''Calculates vals from excel from the given dimensions'''

     def dimension():   # Maybe exchange exec-statement with the function itself.
    if count == 0:
        if inputweight != 0:
            exec scale_weight()
        elif inputlenght != 0:
            exec scale_lenght()
        elif inputspeed != 0:
            exec scale_speed()


def scale_weight(x1, x2):        # Repeat for each value.
    for weightvalue in locate_vals():
        if count == 0:
            x1 * weightvalue == inputweight
            count += 1
            exec criteria2
            return weightvalue, x1
        elif count == 2:
            inputweight2 = int(raw_input('Insert weight')) #inputbox for weight
            x2 * weightvalue == inputweight2
            return weightvalue, x2
```

The x1 and x2 are what I want to find with this function, so I want them to be totally "free". Is there any way I can test this function without having to insert values for x1 and x2 ?

```
def scale_lenght():  # Almost identical to scale_weight
    return


def scale_speed():  # Almost identical to scale_weight
    return


def criteria2(weight, lenght, speed):
    if count == 1:
        k2 = raw_input('Criteria two, write weight, length or speed.')
        if k2 == weight:
            count += 1
            exec scale_weight
        elif k2 == lenght:
            count += 1
            exec scale_lenght
        elif k2 == speed:
            count += 1
            exec scale_speed
        else:
            return
```

Do you see any easier way to deal with this problem?(Hope I managed to explain it well enough. The way I have written the code so far is quite messy, but since I'm not that experienced I'll just have to make it work first, and then clean it up if I have the time.

Since probably none of the values will exactly fit for both x-constants, I thought I'd use approx_Equal to deal with it:

```
def approx_Equal(x1, x2, tolerance=int(raw_input('Insert tolerance for scaling difference')),err_msg='Unacceptable tolerance', verbose = True ):  # Gives the approximation for how close the two values of x must be for 
    if x1 == x2:
         x = x1+ (x2-x1)/2
         return x
```

Eventually, I'd like a diagram of all the variables used + a link-to-file and name for each document.

No sure how I will do this, so any tips are greatly appreciated.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the first question "How come I only get one result when I am printing excelfiles()" this is because your return statement is within the nested loop, so the function will stop on the first iteration. I would try building up a list instead and then return this list, you could also combine this with the issue of checking the name e.g. :

```
import os, fnmatch

#globals
start_dir = os.getenv('md')

def excelfiles(pattern):
    file_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_dir):
        for filename in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename.lower(), pattern):
                if filename.endswith(".xls") or filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith(".xlsm"):
                    file_list.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return file_list

file_list = excelfiles('*cd*')
for i in file_list: print i
```

Obviously, you'll need to replace the *cd* with your own search text, but keep the * either side and replace the start_dir with your own. I have done the match on filename.lower() and entered the search text in lower case to make the matching case in-sensitive, just remove the .lower() if you don't want this. I have also allowed for other types of Excel files.

Regarding reading data from Excel files I have done this before to create an automated way of converting basic Excel files into csv format. You are welcome to have a look at the code below and see if there is anything you can use from this. The xl_to_csv function is where the data is read from the Excel file:

```
import os, csv, sys, Tkinter, tkFileDialog as fd, xlrd

# stop tinker shell from opening as only needed for file dialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

def format_date(dt):
    yyyy, mm, dd = str(dt[0]), str(dt[1]), str(dt[2])
    hh, mi, ss = str(dt[3]), str(dt[4]), str(dt[5])

    if len(mm) == 1:
        mm = '0'+mm
    if len(dd) == 1:
        dd = '0'+dd

    if hh == '0' and mi == '0' and ss == '0':
        datetime_str = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy
    else:
        if len(hh) == 1:
            hh = '0'+hh
        if len(mi) == 1:
            mi = '0'+mi
        if len(ss) == 1:
            ss = '0'+ss
        datetime_str = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy+' '+hh+':'+mi+':'+ss

    return datetime_str

def xl_to_csv(in_path, out_path):
    # set up vars to read file
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(in_path)
    sh1 = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    row_cnt, col_cnt = sh1.nrows, sh1.ncols

    # set up vars to write file
    fileout = open(out_path, 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(fileout)

    # iterate through rows and cols
    for r in range(row_cnt):

        # make list from row data
        row = []
        for c in range(col_cnt):
            #print "...debug - sh1.cell(",r,c,").value set to:", sh1.cell(r,c).value
            #print "...debug - sh1.cell(",r,c,").ctype set to:", sh1.cell(r,c).ctype

            # check data type and make conversions
            val = sh1.cell(r,c).value
            if sh1.cell(r,c).ctype == 2: # number data type
                if val == int(val):
                    val = int(val) # convert to int if only no decimal other than .0
                #print "...debug - res 1 (float to str), val set to:", val
            elif sh1.cell(r,c).ctype == 3: # date fields
                dt = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(val, 0) # date no from excel to dat obj
                val = format_date(dt)
                #print "...debug - res 2 (date to str), val set to:", val
            elif sh1.cell(r,c).ctype == 4: # boolean data types
                val = str(bool(val)) # convert 1 or 0 to bool true / false, then string
                #print "...debug - res 3 (bool to str), val set to:", val
            else:
                val = str(val)
                #print "...debug - else, val set to:", val

            row.append(val)
            #print ""

        # write row to csv file
        try:
            writer.writerow(row)
        except:
            print '...row failed in write to file:', row
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            lines = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
            for line in lines:
                print '!!', line

    print 'Data written to:', out_path, '\n'

def main():
    in_path, out_path = None, None

    # set current working directory to user's my documents folder
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getenv('userprofile'),'documents'))

    # ask user for path to Excel file...
    while not in_path:
        print "Please select the excel file to read data from ..."
        try:
            in_path = fd.askopenfilename()
        except:
            print 'Error selecting file, please try again.\n'

    # get dir for output...
    same = raw_input("Do you want to write the output to the same directory? (Y/N): ")
    if same.upper() == 'Y':
        out_path = os.path.dirname(in_path)
    else:
        while not out_path:
            print "Please select a directory to write the csv file to ..."
            try:
                out_path = fd.askdirectory()
            except:
                print 'Error selecting file, please try again.\n'

    # get file name and join to dir
    f_name = os.path.basename(in_path)
    f_name = f_name[:f_name.find('.')]+'.csv'
    out_path = os.path.join(out_path,f_name)

    # get data from file and write to csv...
    print 'Attempting read data from', in_path
    print ' and write csv data to', out_path, '...\n'
    xl_to_csv(in_path, out_path)

    v_open = raw_input("Open file (Y/N):").upper()
    if v_open == 'Y':
        os.startfile(out_path)
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Let me know if you have any questions on this.

Finally, regarding the output I would consider writing this out to a html file in a table format. Let me know if you want any help with this, I will have some more sample code that you could use part of.

**UPDATE**

Here is some further advice on writing your output to a html file. Here is a function that I have written and used previously for this purpose. Let me know if you need any guidance on what you would need to change for your implementation (if anything). The function expects a nested object in the data argument e.g. a list of lists or list of tuples etc. but should work for any number of rows / columns:

```
def write_html_file(path, data, heads):
    html = []
    tab_attr = ' border="1" cellpadding="3" style="background-color:#FAFCFF; text-align:right"'
    head_attr = ' style="background-color:#C0CFE2"'

    # opening lines needed for html table
    try:
        html.append('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" ')
        html.append('"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> ')
        html.append('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">')
        html.append('<body>')
        html.append('  <table'+tab_attr+'>')
    except:
        print 'Error setting up html heading data'

    # html table headings (if required)
    if headings_on:
        try:
            html.append('    <tr'+head_attr+'>')
            for item in heads:
                html.append(' '*6+'<th>'+str(item)+'</th>')
            html.append('    </tr>')
        except:
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            lines = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
            print 'Error writing html table headings:'
            print ''.join('!! ' + line for line in lines)

    # html table content
    try:
        for row in data:
            html.append('    <tr>')
            for item in row:
                html.append(' '*6+'<td>'+str(item)+'</td>')
            html.append('    </tr>')
    except:
        print 'Error writing body of html data'

    # closing lines needed
    try:
        html.append('  </table>')
        html.append('</body>')
        html.append('</html>')
    except:
        print 'Error closing html data'

    # write html data to file
    fileout = open(path, 'w')
    for line in html:
        fileout.write(line)

    print 'Data written to:', path, '\n'

    if sql_path:
        os.startfile(path)
    else:
        v_open = raw_input("Open file (Y/N):").upper()
        if v_open == 'Y':
            os.startfile(path)
```

headings_on is a global that I have set to True in my script, you will also need to import traceback for the error handling to work as it is currently specified.

Comment: ChrisProsser: "In answer to the first question "How come I only get one result when I am printing excelfiles()" this is because your return statement is within the nested loop, so the function will stop on the first iteration." - Of course! Thanks:) 
Creating a list worked much better as well. Will have a look at your script for converting Excel to CSV now, and see where it gets me. Will update my post after that:)  Thanks again for quick response:)

Comment: Just finished editing the start of the script. Thanks again, it works much better now! If you could give me a few tips regarding the table format as well I would appreciate it!

Comment: I have updated the answer with a sample function that you could use to write to and open a html file.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) looking through it now.

Comment: I forgot to mention, you will presumably want to make one of the columns in the HTML into a link to the Excel file. If the data you pass in has a column containing the path to the file then you can either do something to check if it is a path when iterating through the items for each row or you can just hard code the column index. You can then use the href tag inside of the normal <td> tag (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp). Let me know if you need more specifics.